# MediaPlayer и Animate в Delphi.

Tags: mediaplayer, delphi

В моём самоучителе по Delphi идёт речь о компонентах MediaPlayer и Animate. Где их найти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MediaPlayer на закладке System, а Animate - на Win32.

Answer (score 1):

Они в System !